# Background image not showing, only showing one image

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page design like this (marked in the blue line):

[image]

I have designed all of them with my basic knowledge in CSS. There are three images in the background. I am trying to add them, but it is only showing one image.

My code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-bg">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="logo"><img src="images/page1/image 1.png" alt="" /></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="normal-btn"><a href="#">Sign In</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="normal-btn">
            <a href="#"> <img src="images/page1/Vector.svg" alt="" /></a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <header class="wrapper">

      <div class="left-card">
        <div class="card-cap">
          Year’s end is neither an end nor a beginning but a going on.
        </div>
        <p>
          Join us to celebrate the last night of the year across the country.
        </p>
        <div class="blue-btn"><a href="#">Create account</a></div>
        <div class="reg">
          <img src="images/page1/Ellipse 490.svg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/page1/Ellipse 491.svg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/page1/Ellipse 492.svg" alt="" />
          <p>+ 23547 registrations</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-row">
        <div class="content-box">
        <div class="ctbx-head">
          <img src="images\page1\Vector (1).svg" alt="" />A single source of
          truth
        </div>
          <p>
            When you add work to your Slate calendar we automatically calculate
            useful insights
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box">
        <div class="ctbx-head">
          <img src="images\page1\Vector (2).svg" alt="" />Intuitive interface
        </div>
          <p>
            When you add work to your Slate calendar we automatically calculate
            useful insights
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box">
        <div class="ctbx-head">
          <img src="images\page1\Vector (3).svg" alt="" />Or with rules
        </div>
        <p>
          When you add work to your Slate calendar we automatically calculate
          useful insights
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper2">
      <footer>
        <div class="card">
          <h3 class="card-head">Add New Account</h3>
          <div class="form">
            <form action="">
              <div class="column">
              <div class="input-row">
                 <label for="name" class="lab">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="n-field"/>
              </div>
                <div class="input-row">
                  <label for="email" class="lab">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" class="t-field"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
              <div class="input-row">
                  <label for="organisation" class="lab">Organisation</label>
                  <input type="text" class="t-field"/>
              </div>
                  <div class="input-row">
                  <label for="role" class="lab">Role</label>
                  <select name="role" id="role" class="d-field">
                    <option value="scholar">scholar</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="input-row">
                  <label for="pass" class="lab">Password:</label>
                  <div class="pass-container">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    autocomplete="current-password"
                    class="t-field"
                  />
                  <span class="password-toggle" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility()"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="input-row">
                 <label for="cpass" class="lab">Confirm Password</label> 
                 <div class="pass-container">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    id="c_password"
                    autocomplete="current-password"
                    class="t-field"
                  />
                  <div class="cpassword-toggle" onclick="toggleCPasswordVisibility()"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="input-row">
                <label for="summary" class="lab">Profile summary:</label>
                <textarea name="summery" id="" cols="" rows="10" class="t-field" style="width: 735px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
              <a href="#">Already have an account ?</a>
              <div class="container">
              <button type="submit" class="blue-btn">Create account</button>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    padding-top: 150px;
    height: 1390px;
}

.wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2E333A 60%, #000000);
    z-index: -1;
}

.wrapper::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 1280px;
    width: 590px;
    height: 571px;
    background-image: url('images/page1/1.svg');
    z-index: 0;
}
.wrapper::after:nth-child(2)  {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 650px;
    left: 1480px;
    width: 590px;
    height: 571px;
    background-image: url('images/page1/2.svg');
    z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper::after:nth-child(3) {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 625px;
    left: 980px;
    width: 590px;
    height: 571px;
    background-image: url('images/page1/3.svg');
    z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper::before,
.wrapper::after {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper2{
    height: fit-content;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #2E333A 60%, #000000);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar {
    z-index: 120;
    display: flex;
width: 1920px;
padding: 20px 80px;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
align-self: stretch;
position: fixed;
    
}
nav ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    gap: 28px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.normal-btn{
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    gap: 10px;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: 6.223021507263184px 6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #000, -6.223021507263184px -6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #3B4451;
    color: var(--blue-grey, #B2C2CB);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%;
}
.left-card{
    z-index: 100;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 40px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 70px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    
    box-shadow: -7px -7px 30px 0px #262E32, 14px 14px 40px 0px rgba(16, 16, 18, 0.75);
}
.card-cap{
    z-index: 100;
    height: auto 270px;
    width: 969px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 69px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.left-card p{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 536px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%; 
}
.blue-btn{
    z-index: 100;
    color: var(--secondary-blue, #0ED2F6);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 130%; 
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #0ED2F6;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: 6.223021507263184px 6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #000, -6.223021507263184px -6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #3B4451;
}
.reg{
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.reg img{
    margin-left: -35px;
}
.reg p{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #FFF;
    /* Poppins/18/Medium */
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%;
}
.content-row{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 80px;
    margin-top: 185px;
    padding-bottom: 60.34px;
}
.content-box{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    
}
.ctbx-head{
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    color: var(--light-text, #FFF);
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 23px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 130%; 
}
.content-box p{
    z-index: 100;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: var(--light-text, #FFF);
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%; 
    
}
.wrapper2 .card{
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 60px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:  835px;
    height:  923px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: -7px -7px 30px 0px #262E32, 14px 14px 40px 0px rgba(16, 16, 18, 0.75);
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.card .card-head{
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    padding: 50px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--secondary-blue, #0ED2F6);
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 130%;
}
.card .form{
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}
.card .form .input-row{
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.form .input-row .lab{
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    color: var(--secondary-blue-light-1, #72E4F9);
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
.form .input-row .n-field{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 350px;
    height: 47px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #0ED2F6;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: 3.7338130474090576px 3.7338130474090576px 6.223021507263184px 0px #000 inset, -6.223021507263184px -6.223021507263184px 6.223021507263184px 0px #3B4451 inset;
    color: var(--blue-grey, #B2C2CB);
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%; 
}
.form .input-row .t-field{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 350px;
    height: 47px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: 3.7338130474090576px 3.7338130474090576px 6.223021507263184px 0px #000 inset, -6.223021507263184px -6.223021507263184px 6.223021507263184px 0px #3B4451 inset;
    color: var(--blue-grey, #B2C2CB);
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%;
}
.form .input-row .d-field{
    z-index: 100;   
    width: 350px;
    height: 47px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: 6.223021507263184px 6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #000, -6.223021507263184px -6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #3B4451;
    color: var(--blue-grey, #B2C2CB);
    text-align: start;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%;
    appearance: none;
    background-image: url("images/page1/CombinedShape.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 1rem center;
    background-size: 1em;

}
.column{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
.pass-container{
    position: relative;
}
#password {
    padding-right: 30px; 
  }
  .password-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url('images/page1/Group33537.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  #password.reveal { 
    text-security: none;
  }
  #c_password {
    padding-right: 30px; 
  }
  .cpassword-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url('images/page1/Group33537.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  #c_password.reveal {
    text-security: none;
  }
  .form a{
    color: var(--secondary-blue-light-1, #72E4F9);
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 130%; /* 18.2px */
    text-decoration-line: underline;
  }
  .form .blue-btn{
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #0ED2F6;
    background: var(--dark-colour, #2E333A);
    box-shadow: 6.223021507263184px 6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #000, -6.223021507263184px -6.223021507263184px 18.669065475463867px 0px #3B4451;
    color: var(--secondary-blue, #0ED2F6);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 130%; 
  }
```

It is showing something like shown below. Where are the other images and how can I position it properly?

[image]

What is my error and how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain more about what actually you want? Which part of the code is not working? What is the expected behavior and what have you got?

Comment: bro You see the 3 pictures in the right side of the screen which is given in the background in the first image i want exactly like that. but after I add them to background it is only showing one image which you can see the second image